# npm install does not build vendor executables

Tags: node.js

TL;DR: Why doesn't npm build binary executables of dependencies, and how can I build them without explicitly `npm rebuild`ing them?

My project describes its dependencies in a regular package.json. When I run `npm install`, all of the packages get installed in node_modules as expected. However, three packages have vendor subdirectories which are supposed to have binary executables in them, and they are not being compiled as expected.

> $ ls /usr/src/app/node_modules/optipng-bin/vendor/
>   ls: cannot access /usr/src/app/node_modules/optipng-bin/vendor/: No such file or directory

To work around this, I need to run "npm rebuild " on each of the 3 packages:

- npm rebuild node-sass
- npm rebuild jpegtran-bin
- npm rebuild optipng-bin

> $ npm rebuild optipng-bin
>
> > optipng-bin@3.0.4 postinstall /usr/src/app/node_modules/optipng-bin
>   > node lib/install.js
>
> ✔ optipng pre-build test passed successfully
>
> optipng-bin@3.0.4 /usr/src/app/node_modules/optipng-bin
>
> $ ls /usr/src/app/node_modules/optipng-bin/vendor/
>   **optipng**

When I run `npm rebuild` on its own, I thought perhaps it would "know" to build each of these, but instead, it rebuilds some of the other packages (which do not have executables):

> $ npm rebuild
>
> > history@1.13.1 postinstall /usr/src/app/node_modules/history
>   > node ./npm-scripts/postinstall.js
>
> > react-router@1.0.0 postinstall /usr/src/app/node_modules/react-router
>   > node ./npm-scripts/postinstall.js
>
> > spawn-sync@1.0.13 postinstall /usr/src/app/node_modules/spawn-sync
>   > node postinstall

How can I get npm to install the binary executables belonging to these 3 dependencies in their vendor directories (without an explicit `rebuild` for each)?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a bug in npm 3.3.7 (and possibly other versions of npm). Upgrading to npm 3.5.3 fixed it for me. See https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6679

Answer (score 0):

If vendor executables are missing, it may be because of an architecture mismatch. This can happen when working in and out of Docker containers or switching from x86 to Arm.

First try deleting **node_modules** and **package-lock.json**, then `npm install`. If that doesn't work, executables may be able to be force-build with `npm rebuild --force <module_name>`.